# Activating a Cortana Command programmatically UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, cortana

When you say "Hi Cortana", Cortana listens for a command. For example: Take a picture, or shut down or else.

I want to do this programaticaly in UWP (C#) . Execute a command like "Take a picture" or "Shut down" in UWP. (It doesnt matter if the user is asked weather they want that action to be taken, that is, I am not trying to bypass security or do something evil that the user doesnt want. )

I dont want to create a new capability, but just use existing ones. Preferably using a text string.
For example: I want to shut down the device. I want to replicate the process:
"hey cortana" "Shut Down" "Yes" that the user says.
I want to create a function that does this

```
void ExecuteCommand(String command) {......}
```

And if I call `ExecuteCommand ("shut down");` The device shuts down

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking to integrate your app with Cortana or do you need functionality similar to how Cortana works? In case of the latter I would recommend looking at the `windows.media.speechrecognition` namespace

Comment: The second would be better as i dont want cortana to appear. But I dont care about the speechrecognition part. I just want to activate the commands. 
For example: I want to shut down the device. I want to replicate the process:
"hey cortana" "Shut Down" "Yes" that the user says.
I want to create a function that does this 
void ExecuteCommand(String command) {......}
And if I call ExecuteCommand ("shut down"); The device shuts down

Comment: I dont want to get a command from the user. I just want to execute it.

Comment: Afaik there is no API (yet) that makes it that easy. From my understanding of the speechrecognition API your app is to listen to spoken commands and ideally the UI is built around that to interact with the user in that manner

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

I understand you want to interact with a background app in Cortana like the following example shows:
[image: cortana-progress-screen]

> This is an example of a progress screen for an app called Adventure
>   Works. In this example, a user has canceled a trip to Las Vegas. The
>   progress screen includes a message customized for the action, an icon,
>   and a content tile with information about the trip being canceled.

In order to do so, you'll have to use the following APIs:

- [Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn706594)
- [VCD elements and attributes v1.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn706593)
- [Voice Command Definition (VCD) elements and attributes v1.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn706593)

You can get started by using the Cortana voice command sample of the Adventure Works app from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand) that is related to the following documentations:

- [Activate a foreground app with voice commands through Cortana](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/voice-commands/launch-a-foreground-app-with-voice-commands-in-cortana)
- [Activate a background app in Cortana using voice commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/voice-commands/launch-a-background-app-with-voice-commands-in-cortana)
- [Interact with a background app in Cortana](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/voice-commands/interact-with-a-background-app-in-cortana)

Comment: I dont want to interact with the user via voice.
I want to activate an app or command just as you do in Cortana. Possibly without using Cortana. Or by calling Cortana and giving a string programaticaly.
I want a method that when i call ExecuteCommand ("shut down"); it does the same thing as Cortana does when I tell her "hey cortana" "Shut down" "Yes"

Comment: You can use the following to achieve that `var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown","/s /t 0");
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(psi);` and use the [FullTrustProcessLauncher Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher) to activate the full-trust Win32 component of an application from a Universal Windows app component in the same application package.

Comment: First of all, the shutting down was an example, not the only thing i want to do.
Second, say that i found the name of the app i want to execute, in this example "shutdown", the code you provided does nothing in my uwp app. I want to debug, or start without debugging. Do I need to create a package? Or can i do in my app manifest? How to call its methods related to the code you entered?

Comment: You can try using the [`Launcher Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Launcher) for that.

Comment: Laucher Class launches a file. What file would i launch? Can you give me a step by step?

Comment: Yes, the `Launcher Class` does what you just mentioned in your previous comment, you can't use Cortana's logic with your own interface which is a UWP app in your case, so you'll have to find alternatives like using the Launcher Class, or the example I provided in a previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174678/discussion-between-kristjan-kica-and-ali-heikal).